# Quasi-concavity of a function

Tags: convex-geometry

I'm trying to show the following function is quasi-concave in $x$
$$\sum^n_{i=0}{n\choose i}F(x)^{i}(1-F(x))^{n-i}u(i)$$
Here, $x$ is defined on $[0,1]$ and $F$ maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, and is a strictly increasing in $x$. So, the function is a convex combination of $u(1)$ to $u(n)$, and I want to know whether the function is quasi-concave in the weights.

Comment: The (not very classical) definition of quasiconcavity can be found here (https://web.mit.edu/14.102/www/notes/lecturenotes1007)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the link, but it looks like the link is not open to the public. Certificate error pops up if I click the link.. Do you know of any other link contains the definition?

Comment: @JeanMarie Please ignore my previous comment. I found the lecturenote you mentioned.